# How variable values are changed

Tags: c

As I know we have to use pointers when we want to change a value of a variable outside the function, as shown here:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_function_call_by_value.htm.
But I don't understand why I am able to change the value of variable `name` inside the function.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
#define MaxNameSize 14
#define MaxNamebuffer MaxNameSize+1
#define MaxNames 8

int main()
{

    void StringInsertionSort(int, int, int max, char [][MaxNamebuffer]);
    char name[MaxNames][MaxNamebuffer] = { "Taylor, Victor","Duncan, Denise","Ramdhan, Kamal","Singh, Krishna","Ali, Mechael","Sawh, Anisa","Khan, Carol","Owen, David" };
    StringInsertionSort(0, MaxNames - 1, MaxNamebuffer, name);
    printf("\nThe sorted names are:\n\n");
    for (int h = 0; h < MaxNames - 1; h++)
    {
        printf("%s \n", name[h]);
    }
    return(0);
}


void StringInsertionSort(int lo,int hi,int max, char list[][MaxNamebuffer])
{
    char key[MaxNamebuffer];
    for (int h = lo + 1; h <= hi; h++)
    {
        strcpy(key, list[h]);
        int k = h - 1;
        while (k >= lo && strcmp(key, list[k]) < 0)
        {
            strcpy(list[k + 1], list[k]);
            --k;
        }
        strcpy(list[k + 1], key);
    }

}
```

Comment: Since `name` is a (2D) array, it is passed as a pointer.  Arrays are passed as pointers, not as values.

Comment: Thank your very much for your explanation

Comment: You're not changing the value of name. You're de-referencing name and changing what it points to.

Answer (score 3):

In the argument context of your code `char list[][MaxNamebuffer]` is 100% identical to `char (*list)[MaxNamebuffer]` and both mean `list` is a **pointer** to arrays of `MaxNamebuffer` bytes.

Answer (score 0):

`name` is stocked in `read_write` memory, and can be accessed anywhere is your program as long as you pass it as a parameter.
When you pass the array as `name` instead of `name[x][y]` for example, it is considered as a pointer, pointing to the first element of the array and enabling your program to write into it.
Alternatively, passing `(name + 2)` would have the effect of passing a pointer to the 2+1 element of `name`. Hope this helps!